# Handling Multiple Places ID trick

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Currently I have 3 tables countries, routes and route_place

countries

- id
- name

table routes

- id
- title

table route_place

- id
- parent_id (id from table routes)
- from (id from countries)
- to (id from countries)
- place_name

I have 3 destination China - Dubai - London from countries table, currently I save the data into route_place table like this:

- China (from column) - Dubai (to column)
- Dubai (from column) - London (to column)

I wanted to save the data into the route_place like this

- China (from column) - Dubai (to column)
- China (from column) - London (to column)
- Dubai (from column) - London (to column)

I couldnt figured the logic after an hour, is there any method or some guidelines for it

for instance, I submitted China - Dubai - London routes, and manually choose routes place by sequence

- China - Dubai
- Dubai - London

what I wanna do is it will automatically create another route from China to London without needing me to insert manually, because China to is one way trip to London too by sequence.

Comment: You're looking for a pivot table. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

Comment: can you exlpain more , this is not totaly clair , where the data is comming ? do you want only a php script that insert into the table route_place static information ?

Comment: I have edited the question, did I make myself clear? @MohammedYassineCHABLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
$array = array('China','Dubai','London');

$array_length = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $array_length - 1; $i++){

  for($j = $i+1; $j < $array_length; $j++){

    echo $array[$i] . " to " . $array[$j] .'<br>';

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need the logic, here is my solution when using PHP. Let say that you query all the distinct destination on route_place table (route_place->to) and insert it into $destination variable.

```
foreach($destination as $destination) {
    foreach($route_place as $route_place) {
        if ($route_place->from == $destination->to and $route_place->id != $destination->id) {
            //save this route to database
        }
    }
}
```